# How do I convert a class property to integer

Tags: python, class, properties

I have the following class:

```
class temp_con():
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = 0
    @property
    def t(self):
        return self.t
    @t.setter
    def t(self,value):
        self.t = value
```

I need to use it to compare against a number following this logic:

```
if num <= temp_con.t - 2:
    #dothing
```

However i get the error:

> Type error: unsupported operand type for -: 'property' and 'int'<

I have tried `int(temp_con.t)` and `getattr(temp_con, t)` but those did not work.

How can I utilize the property as an int?

Comment: `return self.t` doesn't return `0`, it returns the function `t` (which is a property getter). You should distinguish between the attribute and the property getter. Set `self._t = 0`

Comment: This question seems to be confused on multiple fronts about the difference between members of a class and members of an instance of a class. For example, `temp_con` is declared as a class, but in the usage example it appears `temp_con` is also being used as a variable which is expected to be an instance.

Comment: answer was a combination of the first 2 answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use separate names for the property and the attribute it wraps. A good convention is to use the property name prefixed with a `_` as the attribute name.

```
class TempCon:
    def __init__(self):
        self._t = 0

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t

    @t.setter
    def t(self, value):
        self._t = value
```

Then you can access the property on an *instance* of the class.

```
temp_con = TempCon()
print(temp_con.t)
temp_con.t = 5
print(temp_con.t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing t on CLASS, not on an OBJECT of CLASS.

Try:

```
q = temp_con()
if num <= q.t - 2:
  pass
```

In you code temp_con.t returns property object, which wraps getter (and setter) you've defined in your class code, but it doesnt execute it.

UPDATE: (memo: read twice)
There's also another problem with your code. First (well, it's second in code, but it will happen first) you define getter `t`, then later you OVERWRITE it with `self.t = 0`. As a result you'll get (as `t`) property accessible as a class member (which happens in your example) and value `0` as object's member.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the class in order to use the property and, as pointed out in other answers, you need to use a different name for your object variable. Try:

```
class temp_con():
    def __init__(self):
        self._t = 0

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t

    @t.setter
    def t(self,value):
        self._t = value

my_temp_con = temp_con()

if num <= my_temp_con.t - 2:
    pass
```

Thus, to access the value of the property and not the property function, you have to access it through `my_temp_con.t`.